# Filtering a dataframe using conditions on multiple columns

Tags: r, filter, data-cleaning

I am trying to filter my data frame and remove all rows that have only NA values for four specific columns. I want to keep rows that contain NA values for some of those columns, just not the ones with NA for all the columns.

I tried to use filter() and specified my desired output, but it automatically takes out all rows with NA for that column. I need to keep rows that have NA for that column, but contain values in at least one of the other three columns. Here is an example of how I tried to use filter:

```
new_data <- filter(data, Q1 == "Female"
                                     Q2 == "Hispanic"
                                     Q3 == "Black"
                                     Q4 == "Native American"
                                     
                      )
```

I need to remove all rows that do not belong to at least one of those groups.

*EDIT* After trying to use if_any(), I got an error "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types" as my data is qualitative

Answer (score 1):

We may use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    filter(if_any(Q1:Q4, complete.cases))
```

Comment: After trying to use if_any(), I got an error "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types" as my data is qualitative

Comment: @MattMurray can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`  without a small reproducible example using `dput`, we can't test it